# String or binary data would be truncated error even though all parameters are within the limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which i use to insert. I get this error when I try to insert by passing these values.

```
exec WorkDetail 'Insert',2,'2015-10-20','se31','entry','title','r','0','abh',
```

`'client','proj','task','status','rea','module','2','4','stat','1'`

This is the stored procedure.

```
    USE [OMS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[WorkDetail]    Script Date: 06/04/2016 09:52:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WorkDetail]
    @QueryType nvarchar(25),
    @ReportNo numeric(18,0),
    @ReportDate date,
    @EmpCode nvarchar(15),
    @Session nvarchar(50),
    @ReportTitle nvarchar(50),
    @ReportDesc nvarchar(Max),
    @ReportType numeric(18,0),
    @CreatedBy nvarchar(50),
    @ClientPlace nvarchar(50),
    @Project nvarchar(50),
    @Task nvarchar(50),
    @TaskStatus nvarchar(50),
    @Reason nvarchar(250),
    @Module nvarchar(50),
    @EntryFrom nvarchar(50),
    @EntryTo nvarchar(50),
    @Status nvarchar(25),
    @SQLReturn nvarchar(MAX) output 

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 Begin Transaction WorkDetails
 Declare @rcount int
 set @rcount=0
     if @QueryType='Insert'
         Begin
            if not exists(select * from WorkDetails where EmpCode=@EmpCode and ReportDate=@ReportDate and Session=@Session)                 
            Begin
                SET @ReportNo=(select ISNULL(MAX(ReportNo),0)+1 from WorkDetails)   
                Insert Into WorkDetails (ReportNo,ReportDate,EmpCode,Session,ReportTitle,ReportDesc,ReportType,Location,Project,Module,Task,TaskStatus,Reason,EntryFrom,EntryTo,Status,ReportTime,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,UpdatedBy,UpdateDate)
                Values(@ReportNo,@ReportDate,@EmpCode,@Session,@ReportTitle,@ReportDesc,@ReportType,@ClientPlace,@project,@Module,@Task,@TaskStatus,@Reason,@EntryFrom,@EntryTo,@Status,GETDATE(),@CreatedBy,GETDATE(),@CreatedBy,GETDATE())
                if @@ROWCOUNT>0
                    set @rcount=1
             End
            else
             set @rcount=-1
         End         
         if @rcount>0
    Begin
        commit transaction WorkDetails
        set @SQLReturn='Success'
    End 
    else if @rcount=-1
    Begin
        commit transaction WorkDetails
        set @SQLReturn='Already'
    End 
    Else
    Begin
        rollback transaction WorkDetails
        set @SQLReturn='Failure'
    End    
END
```

This is the error:

`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure WorkDetail, Line 33
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

I'm new to sql and just came across stored procedure.I saw other questions with this error but I don't understand which field extends the specified limit

Comment: I think problem is in @SQLReturn. Try nvarchar(max) to this variable.

Comment: @gofr1..tried it..didnt work..i will edit question to add more detail

Comment: In that case show SP code, please. :)

Comment: @gofr1..i've posted it

Comment: add more detail ... or for debugging  add veritable for all parm  and   remove snd  execute  with hard coded values..

Comment: @boo hm, you insert data in the table, maybe problem is in that table, it has another size of nvarchar in one of the columns?

Comment: table mach WorkDetails data type... most likely data type miss match there...

Comment: @gofr1. thanks a lot. you were right. the table has `nvarchar(3)`. you can write this as an answer if you want

Comment: Also note:  `@ReportType numeric(18,0)` and you pass `'0'`